# Точка восстановление в Windows 7

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте.

В Windows7 в Защита системы-включил восстановление для двух дисков С и D.

В планировщике заданий-Microsoft-Windows-SystemRestore задаю задание создавать ежедневно точку восстановление в 12-00.

Перепровяряю через несколько дней создалась только одна точка, проверяю далее заметил, что создается одна точка восстановления в неделю.

**Вопрос:** Как сделать, чтобы автоматически по заданию создавалась точка восстановления для диска С и для диска D в 12-00 ежедневно???

Заранее, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Очевидно, что в ситуации, когда в плане было составлено задание на ежедневную работу, а по факту отображается только одна - следует вывод: подсистема резервирования **работает некорректно**. Следовательно, источник проблемы нужно искать **внутри** ОС, используя анализ хотя бы журналов событий. Только после этого имеет смысл искать ответ **вовне**.